# How to pivot by value in pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark, pivot

Here's my input

```
+----+-----+---+------+----+------+-------+--------+
|year|month|day|new_ts|hour|minute|ts_rank|   label|
+----+-----+---+------+----+------+-------+--------+
|2022|    1|  1|    13|  13|    24|      1|       7|
|2022|    1|  1|    14|  13|    24|      1|       8|
|2022|    1|  2|    15|  13|    24|      1|       7|
|2022|    1|  2|    16|  13|    44|      7|       8|
+----+-----+---+------+----+------+-------+--------+
```

Here's my output

```
+----+-----+---+-------+--------+
|year|month|day|     7 |       8|
+----+-----+---+-------+--------+
|2022|    1|  1|     13|      14|
|2022|    1|  2|     15|      16|
+----+-----+---+-------+--------+
```

Here's the pandas code

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index=["year","month","day"], columns="label", values="new_ts").reset_index()
```

What I try

```
df_pivot = df.groupBy(["year","month","day"]).pivot("label").value("new_ts")
```

Note: sorry I can't show my error message here, because I'm using cloud solution and its only show the line of error not error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupBy("year","month","day").pivot('label').agg(first('new_ts')).show()


+----+-----+---+---+---+
|year|month|day|  7|  8|
+----+-----+---+---+---+
|2022|    1|  1| 13| 14|
|2022|    1|  2| 15| 16|
+----+-----+---+---+---+
```